# Issues with VS Code Durable Function Monitor Extension (Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')"

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-durable-functions

I am having an issue while using the Durable Function Monitor extension. When I try to open any durable function it gives me the below error "Func: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')"

Solution is implemented in Visual studio 2022. I am using VS Code to use the Durable Function Monitor Extensions.I also installed Azure tool extension.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Durable Function Monitor extension in visual studio code to check the same in my environment.

[image]

Initially, I was also unable to use Durable function Monitor extension.

-As mentioned in the [github issue](https://github.com/scale-tone/DurableFunctionsMonitor/issues/19), after ***installing latest version of Azure function core tools***, I could connect and use the extension for durable functions.

[image]

[image]